# Perform two computations in parallel without using ParallelTable or ParallelMap

Tags: parallelization

I have two functions, `f` and `g`, that I wish to apply to large data sets, `data1` and `data2`, and assign them to variables `X` and `Y`. Because `data1` and `data2` are large, and because `f` and `g` are computationally demanding ("expensive"), I wish to do the following computations **in parallel:**

```
X = f[data1];
Y = g[data2];
```

or, likewise,

```
{X, Y} = {f[data1], g[data2]};
```

**How do I compute `X` and `Y` in parallel *in general*?** The answer to this question seems like it should be obvious, but it's not obvious to me.

If `f` and `g` were identical, I could use [`ParallelMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelMap.html), for example:

```
{X, Y} = ParallelMap[f, {data1, data2}];
```

Similarly, if `data1` and `data2` were identical, I *might* be able to use [`ParallelTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html):

```
{X, Y} = ParallelTable[i[data1], {i, {f, g}]
```

But how can I compute `X` and `Y` in parallel *in general*?

I have tried the following methods -- (1), (2), and (3) -- and the results seem to suggest that either I am not using [`Parallelize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelize.html) correctly or what I'm trying to accomplish cannot be done with [`Parallelize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelize.html).  In the following, I have used example functions (calculating lengths of the result of [`FactorInteger`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorInteger.html)) in place of my own functions, `f` and `g`, since they are rather complicated. So I've borrowed the idea for a simple yet "expensive" computation using `FactorInteger` from [this documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/RunAComputationInParallel.html).

```
Print["Number of kernels before launch: ", $KernelCount];
LaunchKernels[2];
Print["Number of kernels after launch: ", $KernelCount];

(* Do two "expensive" calculations and assign the results to X and Y, respectively *)
(* (1) Do the computations in sequence *)
AbsoluteTiming[
X = AbsoluteTiming[Table[Length@FactorInteger[10^50 + i], {i, 20}]];
Y = AbsoluteTiming[Table[Length@FactorInteger[10^50 + i], {i, 20}]];
]

(* (2) Attempt in vain to do the computations in parallel using Parallelize *)
AbsoluteTiming[
Parallelize[
X = AbsoluteTiming[Table[Length@FactorInteger[10^50 + i], {i, 20}]];
Y = AbsoluteTiming[Table[Length@FactorInteger[10^50 + i], {i, 20}]];
]]

(* (3) Use Parallel Table to do the computations in parallel;
then assign the results to X and Y *)
AbsoluteTiming[
{X, Y} = ParallelTable[
AbsoluteTiming[Table[Length@FactorInteger[10^50 + i], {i, 20}]], {2}];
]

(* Method (3) speeds up the computations somewhat by performing them in parallel. *)
(* However, if the two computations are significantly different in form,
then ParallelTable cannot in general be used -- as far as I can tell. *)
```

> Number of kernels before launch: 0

> Number of kernels after launch: 2

> `{5.209785, Null}`

> `{5.100558, Null}`

> `{4.185426, Null}`

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`ParallelSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelSubmit.html) (introduced in version 7.0) and [`WaitAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WaitAll.html) to do what you want simply and effectively.  But first a hopefully illuminating example as to how `ParallelSubmit` works.

## Evaluation sequence of ParallelSubmit

```
(*job1*)ParallelSubmit[Labeled[Pause[2]; TimeObject[Now], $KernelID]]
(*job2*)ParallelSubmit[Labeled[TimeObject[Now], $KernelID]]
WaitAll@Out[{-2, -1}]
```

[image]

As we can see, `job2` completed *before* `job1` even though it normally (i.e. without `ParallelSubmit`) would enter the evaluation stack *after* `job1`.  So `WaitAll` submits these tasks to be evaluated at the same time (flagged to be evaluated on different kernels), *Mathematica* receives the collection of tasks, sends each of them onto their own kernel, then evaluates them simultaneously.  I'm thinking of it like the internals of a post office sorting facility.

## General usage

So, with that in mind, we can simply wrap each evaluation in a `ParallelSubmit` and then send both with a `WaitAll` as

```
fd1 = ParallelSubmit@f[data1]
gd2 = ParallelSubmit@g[data2]
{X, Y} = WaitAll@{fd1, gd2}
```

Though, when manually evaluating custom functions on parallel/remote kernels, one should take care to make sure the other kernels know the definitions of said functions.  See more on [**Resource Sharing in Parallel Computing**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ResourceSharingInParallelComputing.html).

## FactorInteger example

And in the example we can an "effective" evaluation time by taking maximum of the parallel timings.

```
ParallelSubmit@First@AbsoluteTiming[Table[Length@FactorInteger[10^50 + i], {i, 20}];];
ParallelSubmit@First@AbsoluteTiming[Table[Length@FactorInteger[10^50 + i], {i, 20}];];
Max@WaitAll@Out[{-2, -1}]
```

> 1.21117

**NOTE:** beware of parallel overhead because sometimes sequential evaluation can actually be quicker than doing so in parallel.